# Server 2003: DNS seem to only resolve google.com but no other website

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, internet, web

I have a windows 2003 server running AD, DHCP, DNS and RRAS. I had to remove and re-install AD and DNS last week, after the installation, everything seem to work find except for browsing websites. Google.com, youtube.com opens alright but all other sites don't. When clients try to load yahoo.com for instance, it takes forever and shows "page cannot be displayed". I can however browse all site on the server ok.
Server Local NIC: 192.168.0.2, 255.255.255.0,No gateway DNS: 192.168.0.2,198.6.1.2
Server Internet NIC: 192.168.1.2, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.1.1 DNS: 198.6.1.2, 192.168.1.1

192.168.1.1 is the IP of my ISP broadband modem

Why can't my clients browse other websites in addition to google.com?

Comment: Please provide the output of "ipconfig /all" on your server, and the same output of a client machine on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet. Additionally, check your DNS forwarder settings: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323380#7

Comment: `1.` Don't use any DNS server(s) other than your AD DNS server(s) in the DNS client settings of the server. `2.` Why is your server dual-homed? `3.` You have your forwarders pointing back to the server itself. How do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 0):

Check your dns redirector in your dns .

If its ok on the server its because you use external dns directly . But client in dhcp normaly use your ad server . And ad server is dns .

Comment: The forwarders on my DNS Server are the same Primary and Secondary DNS settings on the internet NIC on the server machine. DHCP is also set to give the IP address of the Local NIC as primary DNS and  my DNS forwarders as alternate DNS.